# INSERT query PDO single quotation PDO Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I have this query where I am inserting information into a database. 
Submitting the form works as intended. However, when using ' (apostrophes) within the text entered,
I receive a **PDOException SQLSTATE[42000] Syntax error or access violation: 1064**

```
$result = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `news_articles` 
                            SET `postedby`=:postedby,`title`=:title,
                                `short_title`=:short_title, 
                                `article_image`=:article_image,
                                `contents`=:contents,
                                `datetime`=:datetime,
                                `event_datetime`=:event_datetime,
                                `type`=:type 
                           WHERE `articleid`=:articleid");
    $result->bindParam(':articleid', $articleid);
    $result->bindParam(':postedby', $postedby);
    $result->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $result->bindParam(':short_title', $short_title);
    $result->bindParam(':article_image', $article_image);
    $result->bindParam(':contents', $contents);
    $result->bindParam(':datetime', $datetime);
    $result->bindParam(':event_datetime', $event_datetime);
    $result->bindParam(':type', $type);
    $result->execute();
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: Do you know which field is causing the issue? And what the data containing the apostrophe looks like

Comment: Is there more to the error such as a stack trace?

Comment: Don't think so Phil.. and yes it should be $contents as we are using TinyMCE editor so when we write an article, if it contains an apostrophe inside, it gives the error shown when submitting,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of this but if you use the third parameter of the `->bindParam()` to inform it of the data type it may well be all you need to correct this issue

So that would be specifically

```
$result->bindParam(':contents', $contents, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

But you should use it on all your `->bindParam()` calls

> Manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
>
> and Param constants http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php

Comment: Worked! So even though no other errors are showing, I should define what type of the data type? I will update that soon then. Thanks RiggsFolly